# Exclude node_modules recursively

Tags: javascript, regex, firebase, mocha.js, regex-negation

I came across a specific issue when setting up Firebase in my project directory.

Initially, project's hierarchy could be summed up by the following :

```
.
./src
./src/my_code.js
./src/my_code.test.js
./node_modules
./node_modules/...
./package.json
```

To run my tests, I'm using mocha.

On this very website, I found a really useful **regexp** able to match all *.test.js files in the whole project hierarchy, except the *node_modules* "branch" :

`./{,!(node_modules)/**}/*test.js`

Next step for me was to initialize Firebase Functions & Hosting in the directory.

A design choice was made to set up the `functions` folder in `./src`.

After running `firebase init` and answering all the questions, my folder looked like that :

```
.
./src
./src/my_code.js
./src/my_code.test.js
// ===== NEW =====
./src/functions
./src/functions/index.js
./src/functions/index.test.js
./src/functions/node_modules
./src/functions/node_modules/...
./src/functions/package.json
// ===============
./node_modules
.node_modules/...
./package.json
```

The problem lies in that **the regexp appears not to exclude the** `./src/functions/node_modules` **folder**.

I'm not really at ease to extend this cool regexp, not knowing if I have to add `**` or a `!(src/functions/node_modules)` somewhere.

Comment: `./{,!(node_modules)/**}/*test.js` is not a regex. Looks like a glob pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I took a deep look into [this mochajs' issue](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1577).

First of all, it appears that, **as @Wiktor mentioned** in my question's comments, `./{,!(node_modules)/**}/*test.js` isn't a regex, but a glob.

I didn't investigated this concept further for now, because `mochajs` now implement an `--exclude` flag feature.

My solution is the following : `mocha \"./**/*test.js\" --exclude \"./**/node_modules/**\"`.